# I am facing problem in linked list in python

Tags: python

I was creating a linked list and was adding a function to get an element at a given position.

I have attached my code below.

In the code I have `current = self.head`. Here `current` is assigned `self.head`. So aren't both of these same?  In the `while` loop when I used `while current` the code works without any error:

```
def get_position(self, position):
    current = self.head
    counter =0
    while current:
        counter+=1
        current=current.next
    print("total elements:",counter)
```

But if I use `while self.head` I get an error:

```
def get_position(self, position):
    current = self.head
    counter =0
    while self.head:
        counter+=1
        current=current.next
    print("total elements:",counter)
```

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'.

[image: In second image I use while self.head. Here I got error]

Please help me in understanding how both of these are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`while self.head` is a condition that will never change, because `self.head` is not changed in the loop (and it shouldn't). So this means that if it is true once, it will always be true.

You might mistakenly think that when a new assignment is made to `current`, that this assignment *also* applies to `self.head`, but that is not true. They are two separate references (an attribute and a variable) that just happen to reference the same node *at the start* of the loop. But if `current` gets to reference a different node, this does not affect what `self.head` references.

Compare it with this trivial situation:

```
a = b = 1
a = 2 
print(b)  # still 1.
```

The same principle holds with `self.head` and `current`.  An *assignment* to `current` will not affect `self.head`.

Now to the exception: the loop's body assigns new values to `current`:

```
current=current.next
```

At some point `current` will reference the last node of the list and then `current.next` is `None`. So when the above assignment happens again, `current` will be `None`. But the loop doesn't end, as `self.head` is unchanged (still references the *first* node), and so the next iteration will evaluate again `current.next`, but that triggers an error, as `None` has no attribute `next`.

Conclusion, your `while` condition should be something that makes the loop exit when `current` is `None`.

Answer (score -1):

You want to check whether the `current` pointer has a (non-`None`) `next` attribute.

```
def get_position(self, position):
        current = self.head
        counter =0[enter image description here][1]
        while current.head: # instead of while self.head:
            counter+=1
            current=current.next
        print("total elements:",counter)
```

> Here current is assigned self.head, so aren't both of these same?

Yes, but only at the time of assignment. You are assigning to the variable `current` the reference that the `self.head` attribute stores. So once this assignment is made, `current == self.head` would give `True`. However, in your loop, you reassign `current` to `current.next`. Remember, despite holding the same value initially, `current` and `self.head` remain two distinct variables. Re-assinging to one of these variables will not affect the other since they are independent.

So once you  reassign to `current`, the variables are no longer the same, and you want to be checking whether the `current` in your loop condition.